# Android Thread and Handler NullPointerException

Tags: android, multithreading

I am a beginner in Android. I am having a NullPointerException for my Handler.

- I am calling a service inside Thread, and using Handler to update the UI in ACTIVITY A.
- I am using Notification to show another ACTIVITY B.

  Suppose I am clicking the notification when the thread is running in ACTIVITY A, THE ACTIVITY B  is calling and after some delay the app crashes, I think the handler lost its context of ACTIVITY A. I want to know how to handle the situation, suppose if I use AsyncTask will the asyncTask takes care of the context problem? Anyone could solve me this please. Thanks in advance.

**ACTIVITY - A :**

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // call service get response
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

when notification is clicked I am displaying Activity B.

logcat o/p is just
NullPointerException in the line of handler.sendMessage
and inside the handler i am updating the UI of Activity B.

Comment: can you post handler definition.

Comment: also you have not started your thread.

Comment: what is in the logcat?

Comment: from this code snippet and without `Logcat`, its not possible trace the problem.

Comment: check whether you started your thread or not.

Comment: @donfuxx I posted in question - a NullPointerException. and it is due to the Handler is null since it does not have the context of ACTIVITY A. I want to stop the thread in onPause. i tried to set the thread to null in onpause but sometimes it is not working

Comment: can you please post full stacktrace of your NPE?

Comment: The Problem is the handler in activity A is null, since Activity B is launched, i want to handle the thread, can anyone tell me

Comment: Inside handler i am modifying the UI of activity A.

Answer (score 1):

I converted the Thread to AsyncTask and if the asyncTask in running when Activity A is in onPause , i am cancelling the AsyncTask which is a temporary fix for the issue. but I am looking for the perfect one.

Answer (score 0):

initialize the handler and also be sure that the message is not null

Comment: The message is not null but the Handler is, since the handler is associated with ACTIVITY A AND I am currently displaying ACTIVITY B.

Comment: will async task do the fix ?? @Lucian Novac

Comment: It can be a solution but you have to pay attention on methodes, on doInBackground make your network actions and in onPostExecute do your ui actions

Comment: I can change the same code
make service call in doInBackground
and Handler in onPostExecute,
but will it fix my issue I mean if the asyncTask is still running when Activity B is started, it should not crash

Comment: you have to go to activity B on your onPostExecute function

Comment: if you go to activity B you will force your asynk to stop.... but not to crash... or depend on what you make on onPOstExecute function if you have ui elements from A and you go to B the app will crash

Comment: The Problem is the handler in activity A is null, since Activity B is launched, i want to handle the thread, can you tell me how

Comment: I think inherity option will help you. A exdend C, B exdend C and in C put your handler